# Spring Boot JWT Refresh Token

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

If JWT Access token gets expired, then we can make use of Refresh Token to generate the new access token for the particularly logged-in user.

My ask is, If a user is performing activities for the last 4 hours 59 minutes(Considering JWT Access Token expiry set to 5 hours), just after 1 minute JWT Access token going to expire, let's say after 1 minutes JWT Access Token got expired, then Why User is going to invoke the refreshToken endpoint means (manually invoke refreshtoken endpoint to get new access token)?

Is it something, refreshToken endpoint gonna automatically trigger just the moment access token expired ? please shed some light here, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking from backend side only. In frontend mostly we creates an axios interceptor. If you get 401 token expire error, you should send refresh token request from frontend and put new token into cookie or session storage etc. Then you will resend unsuccessfull request using axios. Now it must work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

When a 401 request comes down from the front side using the interceptor, it can be processed to update it automatically.

Usually, failed requests are queued and processed.

```
const refresh = async (config: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<AxiosRequestConfig> => {
  const refreshToken = Cookie.get("refreshToken");
  const expireAt = localStorage.getItem("expiresAt");
  let token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");

  if (moment(expireAt).diff(moment()) < 0 && refreshToken) {
    const body = {
      refreshToken,
    };

    const { data } = await axios.post(`https://auth.server.com/auth/token`, body);

    token = data.data.accessToken;
    localStorage.setItem("accessToken", data.data.accessToken);
    localStorage.setItem(
      "expiresAt",
      moment().add(1, "hour").format("yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
    );
  }

  config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;

  return config;
};

const refreshErrorHandle = (err: any) => {
  Cookie.remove("refreshToken");
};

export { refresh, refreshErrorHandle };
```

```
const Api = axios.create({ baseURL: server });

Api.interceptors.request.use(refresh, refreshErrorHandle);

export default Api;
```